# How to test if all divs with class one has also class two in Rails integration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, integration-testing

I would like to test in my Rails integration test, if all divs with class one has also class two and if not, then fail.

There may be other classes, which are not relevant for this test.

This should pass:

```
<div class="one two">...</div>
<div class="one three two">...</div>
<div class="two one">...</div>
```

And this should fail:

```
<div class="one two">...</div>
<div class="one three">...</div>
<div class="one">...</div>
```

thx!

Comment: There may be work-arounds depending on your reason for adding both classes. If it's for style reasons, why not put all of the CSS rules in class one? If both are part of integration with a javascript library, then it may make more sense to test the effects of those classes being present, either manually or with a browser testing library such as Webrat or Capybara.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using Capybara.

```
let(:items) { page.find('div.one') }

it "items has both classes" do
  items.each do |item|
    expect(item[:class]).to match(/two/)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thx, this might work, but I am not using Capybara. Just using the default testing stuff shipped with rails. Would be nice if it would work with the given tools..

Comment: Test unit is good for model and controller level things, but it's not very well equipped to work on DOM level tests. You may want to try Rspec or Capybara to test this kind of thing.

Comment: well, not the answer I was hoping to hear, but it seems to be the "right" one, so I accept it as the right answer, thx!

Comment: For example Rails 5 is dropping stuff like assert_template, but still keeping assert_select - but this might be the indication for you, that if you want to test on DOM level, sooner or later you will have to use some external dependency :).